# MassTransit and RabbitMQ, history of messages

Tags: email, rabbitmq, masstransit

my question is more architectural than procedural but I think it will fit the T&C of S.O.

We have an application which is in charge of sending out bulk e-mails.
The architecture is composed as following:

[image]

- A consumer sends a request via MassTransit to prepare an e-mail

  - The e-mail has: HTML Content, Sender, List of receivers

At this point, a second step is executed by a MassTransit Handler:

[image]

This is required because in the first step, an E-mail template is created which might generate 30'000 e-mails. For each e-mail a specific Message is sent to RabbitMQ and the E-mail is sent out individually.

What we need, is an historical of the template and all the e-mails sent out by the Template. Because our platform sends out millions of E-mail (internal e-mails only) we are worried of storing this into SQL Server so I was wondering if there is any way we can query RabbitMQ to get the history of the messages generated and processed or if there is a better way to achieve so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ does not keep a history of messages, once they are dispatched and consumed, any remnants of that message are removed. And nor should it.

If you need to maintain a history for audit purposes, or even for tracking (such as email open callbacks, or unsubscribe links, whatever), you could use any sort of database to track the identifier, destination, date sent, and whatever else is necessary. I wouldn't suggest SQL Server, but if you already have it, you can set up a fairly narrow table partitioned by datetime, and drop old file groups once you no longer want to keep older records (say after 3 months). You could use any data store, it just depends upon what your teams are operationally able to support in production. Adding a new technology might not be optimal or manageable.

You could produce a post-email-sent event that a separate consumer (or batch consumer, given the volume) would consume and write to the audit database separate of the email sender.

Comment: I didn't think about the post-process message. That's briliant :-)
We support many DBs in my Company so I will probably move into a blob to store a JSON of the status of the e-mail.